# run capistrano 3 custom setup scripts as root once

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I've got capistrano 3 running perfectly with passwordless deploy as a non root user.

What I'm trying to do now is setup a install script that install's the upstart service, the sudoers.d file and installs some dependencies on the server.

so that I could install a new server by simply entering the user and host in the production.rb file and run `cap production setupserver`

the problem is that the setup scripts that I've created need to be run as root.

But since it's a one time thing, I'd simply like to ask the user for the root password and run a couple of tasks on the server.

the `as :root` command doesn't work since it uses `su -c`

I could ask for the password as demonstrated here
http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/how-can-i-get-capistrano-to-prompt-for-a-password/

any suggestions on how to override the user specified in the production.rb file?

and how to pass the asked password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I finally solved it was by adding another role for the same server.

```
role :app, 'theappuser@myserver'
role :install, 'root@myserver', :no_release => true
```

And then doing something like this

```
desc 'Install nginx'
task :install do
  on roles(:install) do
    require 'erb'
    template = ERB.new(File.new('deploy/templates/nginx.conf.erb').read).result(binding)
    upload! StringIO.new(template), "/etc/nginx/conf.d/#{fetch(:domain)}.conf"
  end

  on roles(:app) do
    invoke 'nginx:restart'
  end
end
```

Comment: FWIW, in the `server {}` block of a global `nginx.conf` file you can add wildcards to include multiple application-specific configs. You can use something like `include /var/www/apps/*/current/config/nginx.conf;` to pull in application-specific nginx configs which do not need to be installed as root, and can be placed in your rails `config/` directory for each app. Then the only operation you need to run as root after the first deploy is `sudo service nginx restart`.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly this should solve your problem by make the user variable:

`set :current_user, Proc.new { current_user = Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask "Enter deploy user" }`

```
if current_user.present?
   set :user, "#{current_user}"
end
```

what it will do it will ask you before run the command for user then assign this user to production.rb :user, then you will be able to control it on the setup.

Comment: Where do I have to `set :user`? do I need to do it before `on roles(:app) do`? is it set from production.rb before every task?

Comment: right after the method i written above you put user: "#{current_user}"(sorry looks like this is the Capistrano 3 syntax)

Comment: according to the specs I should be able to specify multiple users for the same host, https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/ad4fe5479b8cccafcc2efee161b5e7e67deb7a13/spec/lib/capistrano/configuration/servers_spec.rb#L110 maybe I could specify which user in the roles command?

Comment: yes maybe this article will you http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/role-filtering/